# How do I modify my form partial to handle a has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-one

This is the relevant part of my `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@score) do |f| %>
  <% if @score.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@score.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this score from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @score.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :client_id %><br />
      <%= f.select :client_id, @clients.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
    </div>  

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firm_size %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firm_size %>
  </div>
    .
    .
    .
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This partial works when I have a generic for creating a `Score` and there is a collection of clients passed in through the controller via `clients`.

The issue is when there is just one `client` record....say for a URL like:
`myapp.com/client/6/scores/new/`

Given that I have a `client_id` in the params, it gives me a nil error:

```
undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I solve this for one single `@client` record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using nested resources, so in the case of `myapp.com/client/6/scores/new/` your `new` method in your `ScoreController` should be called.

In this method (or in a before filter), I'm assuming you have a line that's something like:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
```

Now, if you want to use your partial the way yours is built, you either have to ensure, that there's an object that responds to the method `collect` (i.e. an array) with the name of `@clients` or you could go ahead and rewrite your partial and split it up in `if` sections or so...

The error message you get basically means, that when `ScoreController#new` method's being rendered there's no object called `@clients` therefore it's nil, and the `NilClass` has no method `collect`

So I would just do the following in your `ScoreController#new` method:

```
# get your single client
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])

# and simply put it in an array with the name your partial uses
@clients = [ @client ]
```

Now, I'm not sure that's an elegant solution, but it should keep you going...

Comment: Perfect....that one little trick of putting it in an array works. It's not perfect, but it saves me a headache.